# Creating classes programmatically with Stylus

Tags: stylus

I wonder if there's a way to programmatically create classes with stylus using Iterators.

Example:

```
$my-colors = {
  "black":  #344F5E,
  "grey":   #E0E0E3,
}
```

I know there's `define()` but I'm not sure if that works and if so how I would access the key and the value side.

like

```
for col in $rf-colors
  define('rf-bg-' + col @() {
    background-color:
  })
```

Goal is to extend the color pallette and have all classes automatically generated. Maybe I'm using the completely wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [interpolation](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/interpolation.html) with `{}` and a loop on a hash `for $key, $value in $hash`:

```
$my-colors = {
 "black": #000,
 "white": #fff
}

for $name, $color in $my-colors {
  .{$name} {
    background-color: $color
  }
}
```

which will output:

```
.black {
  background-color: #000;
}
.white {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

The `define()` function is used to [define](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/bifs.html#definename-expr-global) variables.